# Lumen swagger integration that supports multiple endpoints

Tags: laravel, swagger-ui, lumen, l5-swagger

I need a package or plugin that supports swagger integration with a lumen project. Also this package must support multiple end points. I need two URL for swagger for the same project.

I have tried using darkaonline/swaggerlume package. This works for a single endpoint but not applicable if we need multiple endpoints. Only I am getting swagger docs in the following url baseUrl/api/documentation. I also need swagger docs for a client like baseurl/api/client.

Please help me to suggest a package that supports multiple end points for swagger for lumen projects. L5-swagger supports multiple URL for swagger but its only supports laravel not lumen I belive.